# Async task getting error

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

I'm having an issue here. I'm trying to retrieve a profile so that I can view it then update it if needed. However, it has been returning that there was an error getting the profile. But, there is no stack trace, only my tags to debug. Can anyone help me?

Here's the fragment:

```
public static class ProfileSectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public ProfileSectionFragment() {

        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        TextView nameDesc, name, contactTV, emailTV, addressTV, postalTV;
        EditText contactET, emailET, addressET1, addressET2, addressET3,
        postalET;
        Button update;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            recLifeCycle_with_savedInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,
                    container, false);

            nameDesc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameDescTV);
            name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            contactTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactTV);
            emailTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailTV);
            addressTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
            postalTV = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postalTV);

            contactET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactET);
            emailET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailET);
            addressET1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addressET1);
            addressET2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addressET2);
            addressET3 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addressET3);
            postalET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postalET);

            update = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);

            Button unlink = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unlinkButton);

            Log.i("User_id profile", user_id);

            new GetProfileAsyncTask((MainActivity) getActivity()).execute(user_id);

            update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (update.getText().equals("Update My Particulars")) {

                        update.setText("Done");

                        contactET.setClickable(true);
                        contactET.setCursorVisible(true);

                        emailET.setClickable(true);
                        emailET.setCursorVisible(true);

                        addressET1.setClickable(true);
                        addressET1.setCursorVisible(true);

                        addressET2.setClickable(true);
                        addressET2.setCursorVisible(true);

                        addressET3.setClickable(true);
                        addressET3.setCursorVisible(true);

                        postalET.setClickable(true);
                        postalET.setCursorVisible(true);

                    }

                    if (update.getText().equals("Done")) {
                        // make async task to update particulars

                        update.setText("Update My Particulars");

                        contactET.setClickable(false);
                        contactET.setCursorVisible(false);

                        emailET.setClickable(false);
                        emailET.setCursorVisible(false);

                        addressET1.setClickable(false);
                        addressET1.setCursorVisible(false);

                        addressET2.setClickable(false);
                        addressET2.setCursorVisible(false);

                        addressET3.setClickable(false);
                        addressET3.setCursorVisible(false);

                        postalET.setClickable(false);
                        postalET.setCursorVisible(false);

                    }
                }

            });

            unlink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.SharedPreferences.clearUserName(getActivity()); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }

        public void addDetails(final Profile profile){

            Log.i("Profile/Profile", profile.toString());

            name.setText(profile.getName());
            contactET.setText(profile.getContact());
            emailET.setText(profile.getEmail());
            addressET1.setText(profile.getAddLine1());
            addressET2.setText(profile.getAddLine2());
            addressET3.setText(profile.getAddLine3());
            postalET.setText(profile.getPostal());
        }
```

Then, here's the async task:

```
public class GetProfileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    MainActivity activityMain;
    Profile profile;

    public GetProfileAsyncTask(MainActivity parent)
    {
        activityMain = parent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean error = false;
        try {
            error = getData(params[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return error;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean error){    
        if(error == true)
        {
            Log.i("GetProfile", "Error at get profile");
            activityMain.errorOccured();
        }
        else
        {
            activityMain.getProfileSuccess(profile);
        }

    } 

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    }


    public Boolean getData(String userId) throws JSONException {

        Boolean error = false;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // specify the URL you want to post to

        try {

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(Constants.HOST_NAME+"/"+Constants.SERVICE_NAME+"/api/Account/"+userId);
            BufferedReader reader;
            StringBuffer sb;
            String line = "";
            String NL="";
            String json;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
            {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                sb = new StringBuffer("");
                line = "";
                NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }

                reader.close();
                json = sb.toString();

                Log.i("profile json",json);
                try
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);   

                    JSONObject attr = jsonObj.getJSONObject(json);
                    profile =  new Profile(); 
                    if(attr.has("Name"))
                    {
                        profile.setName(attr.getString("Name"));
                        profile.setAddLine1(attr.getString("AddressLineOne"));
                        profile.setAddLine2(attr.getString("AddressLineTwo"));
                        profile.setAddLine3(attr.getString("AddressLineThree"));
                        profile.setPostal(attr.getString("PostalCode"));
                        profile.setContact(attr.getString("HomeTel"));
                        profile.setEmail(attr.getString("Email"));

                        Log.i("Async/Profile", profile.toString());

                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    error = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                error = true;
            }
        } 

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // process execption
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = true;
        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // process execption
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = true;
        }

        return error;

    }
}
```

This is the method that the async task calls(It is within the Main Activity):

```
public void getProfileSuccess(Profile profile) {
    final ProfileSectionFragment fragment = (ProfileSectionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getProfileFragmentTag());
    Log.i("Main/Profile", profile.toString());
    fragment.addDetails(profile);
}
```

Then, here's the xml if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentProfile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameDescTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contactET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:hint="Contact Number"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressET1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressET2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressET3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postalTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Postal Code: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postalET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Postal Code"
            android:text="Placeholder" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
            android:text="Update My Particulars"
            android:textColor="#2470FA"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/unlinkButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
            android:text="Unlink Account"
            android:textColor="#2470FA"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Lastly, here's the logcat:

```
10-17 01:35:17.404: I/MYTAG(13333): ProfileSectionFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-17 01:35:17.414: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.414: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.414: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.414: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.424: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.424: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.424: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.424: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.434: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.444: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got Res id for appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.444: W/ResourceType(13333): Skipping entry 0x106009f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
10-17 01:35:17.444: D/TextView(13333): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
10-17 01:35:17.444: D/TextView(13333): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
10-17 01:35:17.464: I/MYTAG(13333): ProfileSectionFragment.onStart
10-17 01:35:17.464: I/MYTAG(13333): ProfileSectionFragment.onResume
10-17 01:35:17.464: I/MYTAG(13333): TicketSectionFragment.onCreateView / savedInstanceState == null
10-17 01:35:17.484: I/MYTAG(13333): TicketSectionFragment.onStart
10-17 01:35:17.484: I/MYTAG(13333): TicketSectionFragment.onResume
10-17 01:35:17.544: I/GetProfile(13333): Error at get profile
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EventsSectionFragment.onPause
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EventsSectionFragment.onStop
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EventsSectionFragment.onDestroyView
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onPause
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onStop
10-17 01:35:18.034: I/MYTAG(13333): EcardSectionFrontFragment.onDestroyView
10-17 01:35:18.054: I/dalvikvm(13333): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
10-17 01:35:18.054: I/dalvikvm(13333): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
10-17 01:35:18.054: I/dalvikvm(13333): JIT_INFO: ME Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
10-17 01:35:18.054: I/dalvikvm(13333):  The trace provoked a spill.
10-17 01:35:18.054: I/dalvikvm(13333): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
10-17 01:35:18.064: I/dalvikvm(13333): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
10-17 01:35:18.064: I/dalvikvm(13333): ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
10-17 01:35:18.064: I/dalvikvm(13333): JIT_INFO: ME Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
10-17 01:35:18.064: I/dalvikvm(13333):  The trace provoked a spill.
10-17 01:35:18.064: I/dalvikvm(13333): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
```

If there is anymore that you need, feel free to say so.

EDIT:
This is the newer logcat info:

```
10-17 02:03:22.904: I/profile json(14252): {"UserID":"S7182827A","Gender":"F","Password":"","Name":"LIM WOAN CHIN","AddressLineOne":"12","AddressLineTwo":"COLLEGE ROAD","AddressLineThree":"","PostalCode":"169852","HomeTel":"07-4346084","Email":"","DateOfBirth":"","UserType":"ALUM","GradYear":"1996","SMSCode":"53348","SMSCodeLastUpdated":"10/16/2014 10:08:08 PM"}
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252): org.json.JSONException: No value for {"UserID":"S7182827A","Gender":"F","Password":"","Name":"LIM WOAN CHIN","AddressLineOne":"12","AddressLineTwo":"COLLEGE ROAD","AddressLineThree":"","PostalCode":"169852","HomeTel":"07-4346084","Email":"","DateOfBirth":"","UserType":"ALUM","GradYear":"1996","SMSCode":"53348","SMSCodeLastUpdated":"10/16/2014 10:08:08 PM"}
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:574)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.asynctask.GetProfileAsyncTask.getData(GetProfileAsyncTask.java:106)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.asynctask.GetProfileAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetProfileAsyncTask.java:44)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at nyp.edu.sg.alumnigo.asynctask.GetProfileAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetProfileAsyncTask.java:1)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-17 02:03:22.904: W/System.err(14252):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-17 02:03:22.904: I/GetProfile(14252): Error at get profile
```

Comment: looks like there's some error when you call getData. Maybe add more Log tags when you catch the exceptions inside the getDate method?

Comment: Looks like I have more logcats to show. I'll add it in.

Comment: what do you expect `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json); JSONObject attr = jsonObj.getJSONObject(json);` to do ?

Comment: I'm not very sure on storing 1 object received from async task. So... pardon my lack of knowledge. Simply, JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json); stores returned JSON to a JSONObject. Then, I read the data using JSONObject attr = jsonObj.getJSONObject(json);. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with this line of code:

```
JSONObject attr = jsonObj.getJSONObject(json);
```

Is *json* a key?

Remove that line. Then your if-statement should be:

```
  if(jsonObj.has("Name"))
```

instead of

```
  if(attr.has("Name"))
```

and then all references of attr needs to be changed to jsonObj

Comment: Just a quick qn. How do I make the textView uneditable unless I press on the Update My Particulars button?